# Not able to build proper junit-5 test case for Aem servlet which returns json response

Tags: unit-testing, servlets, junit, aem

I wrote the below Aem servlet regestired with path type which returns json response:

**SampleDataServlet.java**

```
package com.myproject.core.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.jcr.Binary;
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.ValueFactory;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.ServletResolverConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.commons.jcr.JcrConstants;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageManager;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.myproject.core.utils.CommonConstants;
import com.myproject.core.utils.WCMUtil;

@Component(immediate = true, service = Servlet.class, property = {
        ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_PATHS + "=/bin/newsReleaseServlet/getNewreleaseJsonData",
        Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=News Release json data generator servlet",
        ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_METHODS + "=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET })
public class SampleDataServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleDataServlet.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final String parentPagePath = "/content/myproject/us/en";
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
        Page page = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class).getPage(parentPagePath);

        JsonObject pageObject1 = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray pagesArray = new JsonArray();
        try {
            Iterator<Page> childPages1 = page.listChildren();

            
            while (childPages1.hasNext()) {
                Page childPage1 = childPages1.next();
                String pageTitle = childPage1.getTitle();
                // JsonArray pagesArray = new JsonArray();
                Page page1 = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class).getPage(childPage1.getPath());
                try {
                    Iterator<Page> childPages2 = page1.listChildren();
                    while (childPages2.hasNext()) {
                        Page childPage2 = childPages2.next();
                        JsonObject pageObject = new JsonObject();
                        ValueMap childProps = childPage2.getProperties();
                        if (!(childProps == null) && childProps.containsKey("startDate")
                                && childProps.containsKey("shortDesc") && childProps.containsKey("longDesc")
                                && childProps.containsKey("pageURL") && childProps.containsKey("year")) {
                            pageObject.addProperty("startDate", childProps.get("startDae").toString());
                            pageObject.addProperty("shortDesc", childProps.get("shortDesc").toString());
                            pageObject.addProperty("longDesc", childProps.get("longDesc").toString());
                            pageObject.addProperty("pageURL", WCMUtil.getURL(childProps.get("pageURL").toString()));
                            pageObject.addProperty("year", Integer.parseInt(pageTitle));

                        }
                        if (pageObject != null && !(pageObject.size() == 0)) {
                            pagesArray.add(pageObject);
                        }

                    }

                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("\n Error while iterating pages {} ", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
            pageObject1.add("pagePropertiesJson", pagesArray);

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("\n Error in scheduler {} ", e.getMessage());
        }

        response.setContentType(CommonConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);
        response.getWriter().write(pageObject1.toString());
    }
}
```

I tried with following test junit code but it is failing and throwing multiple errors, can someone please correct me where I am making a mistake?

**SampleDataServletTest.java**

```
package com.myproject.core.servlets;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoSettings;
import org.mockito.quality.Strictness;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
public class SampleDataServletTest {

    @Mock
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    private SlingHttpServletResponse response;

    private SampleDataServlet servlet;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

       
        servlet = new SampleDataServlet();

       
        AemContext context = new AemContext();

       
        context.registerService(SampleDataServlet.class);

       
        context.request(request);
        context.response(response);

       
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);

        try {
            doReturn(writer).when(response).getWriter();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoGet() throws Exception {
       

       
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
       
        when(request.getParameterMap()).thenReturn(parameterMap);

       
        servlet.doGet(request, response);

       
        String jsonResponse = response.getWriter().toString();

       
        assertNotNull(jsonResponse);
       
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
       
    }
```

Please look into the above code and correct the Junit test code, thanks in advance